# Attempted to load class "Util" from namespace with Checkdomain/Holiday Bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

I want to use the bundle https://github.com/checkdomain/Holiday/blob/master/README.md in Symfony2 (is exactly what I am looking for).

Via composer the bundle is located at /vendor/checkdomain/holiday/...

When I am using the function as shown in the example

```
$util    = new \Checkdomain\Holiday\Util();
$holiday = $util->getHoliday('DE', '01.01.2014');
```

I get

```
Attempted to load class "Util" from namespace "Checkdomain\Holiday\lib\Checkdomain\Holiday\Model".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Zend\Code\Scanner\Util" or "Monolog\Handler\Curl\Util"?
```

I tried to fix it via use:

use Checkdomain\Holiday\Util;
or
use Checkdomain\Holiday;

But the error is still there... Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this code works

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Checkdomain\Holiday\Util;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("test", name="test_index")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $util = new Util();
        $holiday = $util->getHoliday('DE', '01.01.2014');

        dump($holiday);
        exit;
    }

}
```